# Ubuntu 14.04 lsof Script efficiency

Tags: arrays, ubuntu-14.04

I'm new to Stack Overflow, have searched for my question, and have come up with partial answers.

I am trying to poll for sftp'd files mounted on an NSF location on Ubuntu 14.04, which I'm not terribly familiar with yet. The script below WORKS, and I got there thanks to Stack Overflow searches. Unfortunately, the script seems to be very inefficient and maxes out CPU for 5-10 seconds at a time, even when the file array is empty! That will be unacceptable when taking this system into production in a month or two. I've anonymized the locations / labeled them so they're easy to follow.

```
#!/bin/bash

#store the fileNames of any 7 zip files in the upload directory into an array
Files=(/mnt/NFStoSFTPServer/*.7z)
Run=($(ls -d /mnt/NFStoSFTPServer/*.7z))

#loop through the array to unzip the files and move them to the application polling directory
if [ -z "$Run" ]; then
     echo "There are no files to upload"
else
for i in "${Files[@]}"
        do
                #check if the file is being used
                check=`lsof | grep $i`
                if [ -z "${check-unset}" ]; then
                        echo $i
                        echo "The file is done uploading"
                        #the file is not being used, so unzip it to the app polling location
                        7z x $i -o/opt/appPollingLocation
                        #rename the tmp file to xml
                        find -L /opt/appPollingLocation -type f -name $
                        while IFS= read -r -d '' FNAME;
                                do
                                mv -- "$FNAME" "${FNAME%.tmp}.xml"
                        done
                        #move the zip file for safe keeping
                        mv $i /opt/archiveLocation
                fi
done
fi
```

What can I do to improve efficiency here? If the lsof check is removed, the process fails, and I'm thinking that might be where the slowdown lies?

The renaming of the .tmp file to .xml is not optional and can't be fixed up-stream, due to some other constraints. The .7z file move *is* optional, but temporarily archiving (and periodically, automatically clearing) these files seems like a good practice that will help our support team in case of an unexpected processing failure.

Again, my goal is to achieve the same results with a smaller performance hit, since this polling will run about every minute.

Appreciate any advice that can be given!

Update 10:52 am EDT: Just tested and realized that I'm mistaken, the "There are no files to upload" message is never being printed, so perhaps my first if statement is not correct.

Update 11:35 am EDT: Found a way to correct the empty array slowness, updated the script to reflect that. The actual rest of the process still maxes out the CPU.

Update 11:58 am EDT: Adding image of htop. LSOF seems to consume 73% of CPU when I kick this script off when there's a handful of .7z files to process
[htop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEISE.png)